# Retrieve 'username' from Articles table

Tags: rest, laravel-5, vuejs2, php-7

I have two tables, 'users' and 'articles'. Articles have a column 'user_id' which is a foreign key that references the user_id in 'users'.

I have in the Articles model this function which should return the user data:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And this works fine when I pass my articles to my viewer and call it in blade template:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <p>{{$article->user->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

But I am trying to use the RESTful approach, so I am rather retrieving my data from JS (VueJS)

```
axios.get('/api/articles')
```

that should fire my Controller's function:

```
public function index()
{
    $books =  bookpost::all();
    return $books;
}
```

So I was wondering if there's a way to append the user names to the JSON array of articles before returning it because in JS I couldn't get to find a way to get the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "eager loading" in your query to help:

```
$books = bookpost::with('user')->get();
```

You may even eager load nested relationships:

```
$books = bookpost::with('user.friends')->get();
```

[Have a look at the documentation for further help](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).